# How to run ASP.NET MVC6 on IIS without publishing application

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to find a way to run MVC6 application on IIS but without actually doing the publish. I am not sure if that is possible, and if not will it be possible in the future?

I would like to have similar behavior like on previous versions where I could easily debug my code and make changes while the application is running under IIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible. Under the root of your project (project.json directory), run the following command:

```
dnu publish --runtime active --out bin/artifacts
```

Once the publish is done, you have some stuff under `bin/artifacts` folder. Point IIS application pool to `bin/artifacts/wwwroot` folder we have just created and it should work. Keep in mind that you at least need .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: I did try it but seems to me that is not what I wanted. Right now every time when I make a change I need to call that `dnu publish` command in order to see my changes on IIS. I would like to see them only by doing `rebuild`.

Answer (score 16):

From your original question (emphasis added):

> I am trying to find a way to run MVC6 application on IIS **but without actually doing the publish**.

From your comment to tugberk (emphasis added):

> Right now every time when I make a change I need to call that dnu publish command in order to see my changes on IIS. **I would like to see them only by doing rebuild.**

## Answer and reasons

**You'll need to publish.** There are at least two reasons:

- IIS needs build output and
- IIS needs a web.config file.

IIS might need a few other things too, about which I'm not aware. So, you'll need to publish. This isn't a big deal: after the onetime setup, publish doesn't take much longer than rebuild does.

Why do you need to publish?

In Visual Studio 2015, if you build an ASP.NET 5 web app, there will be no build output under your solution's directory, and IIS needs build output. [By default Roslyn](http://www.filipekberg.se/2014/10/31/microsoft-compiler-platform-aka-roslyn/) only runs code analysis without emitting build output.

You can change that default, so that Roslyn does emit build output, but that won't produce the web.config file that IIS needs. By going to `View` > `Project Properties` > `Build` and checking "Produce outputs on build", Roslyn will emit output to the `artifacts` directory. E.g:

```
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/MyWebApp.1.0.0.nupkg
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/MyWebApp.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/app/project.json
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/dnx451/MyWebApp.dll
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/dnx451/MyWebApp.pdb
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/dnx451/MyWebApp.xml
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/dnxcore50/MyWebApp.dll
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/dnxcore50/MyWebApp.pdb
artifacts/bin/MyWebApp/Debug/dnxcore50/MyWebApp.xml
```

If you point IIS at the `artifacts` directory, you'll now have the problem of having neither a `wwwroot` nor a `web.config`.

So, you need to publish (or work out some other convoluted solution) for IIS to work with ASP.NET 5. There is a onetime setup if you want to publish from Visual Studio to a local IIS website. After the onetime setup, you can make changes to your code and publish in two clicks. Here's the onetime setup:

- Right click the project.
- Choose Publish.
- Select File System and add a profile name (e.g. inetpub).
- Change the target location to C:\inetpub\MyWebApp
- In Settings, select appropriate settings. E.g.

  - Configuration: Debug
  - Target DNX Version: `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4`
- Click Publish.

Once publish completes, point IIS at `C:\inetpub\MyWebApp\wwwroot` and you will be able to browse to the web site. Further to the point, you can now change your code, publish in two clicks, and refresh your IIS site to see the changes.

## Some gotchas

- If you do choose to publish to `inetpub`, be sure to run Visual Studio as administrator, lest you receive an insufficient permissions error.
- If you accept the default publish location (instead of using inetpub as shown above) watch out for path too long errors (i.e. > 260 characters.)

## Final thoughts

Why not use Visual Studio and `Debug` > `Start without debugging` during development. With Roslyn and Visual Studio 2015, you can make changes *to the code* and see those changes by *refreshing the web browser*. No rebuild is necessary. It's a much nicer workflow.

Comment: This was very helpful. I understand it a lot better now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is a development on IIS question. It's doable but it requires some work. The reason IIS doesn't work out of the box without a publish is because there is no user profile setup on app pools by default. The simplest thing you can do is to enable the user profile on the app pool, that will allow IIS to find the runtime in the user profile folder. On top of that, you require a web.config to specify which version of the runtime to use (dnu publish generates this for you so if you want, you can do a publish and copy the runtime folder). After doing that, pointing IIS to the wwwroot should just work (assuming you setup the right web.config with the right runtime and the right bitness).

You also need the correct AspNet.Loader.dll in the bin folder. If you use visual studio, it'll copy it in the right place.

Comment: When you say to enable the user profile, you mean about the property `Load User Profile`? I have that enabled. After publishing the application,  `web.config`  contains relative paths for the runtime folder. If I try to remove appSettings `runtime-path` it tries to find .dnx in `C:\Users\DefaultAppPool` but the `.dnx` is in my `C:\Users\Zoran Protic` folder. I also tried with pointing absolute address to my .dnx runtime but then I started to get an issue with not able to find dependencies for target framework.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **davidfowl** answer i ran ASP.NET MVC6 on IIS without publishing application. But i still can't start debug it by F5(only by attaching to w3wp.exe).

Anyway i hope it would be helpful:

- In the root of the project add "packages" directory(or name it whatever you like).
- In global.json file add "packages": "packages". e.g.:

```json
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "wrap"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
  },
  "packages": "packages" // <--
}
```

Packages will be now stored in this directory.

- Create a "runtimes" directory in the root of your project.
- Copy a runtimes from %userprofile%/.dnx/runtimes to /path/to/your/project/runtimes
- Create a web.config in wwwroot of you project. e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta4" />
    <add key="dnx-version" value="1.0.0-beta4" />
    <add key="dnx-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="dnx-app-base" value=".." />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="../../../runtimes" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

- Create web application in IIS and point it to your project wwwroot.

My project directory structure:

```
Projects/
  vNext/
    packages/
    runtimes/
      dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4/
      dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4/
      ...
    src/
      vNext/
        wwwroot/        <-- IIS web application points here
          web.config
          ...
        project.json
        ...
    global.json
    vNext.sln
    ...
```

After this you will be able to attach to w3wp.exe and debug your application running  under IIS.